# The phrase "God willing."

Tags: meaning, connotation

Does "God willing" have a religious connotation to it? What are some other phrases that mean the same thing but don't have this connotation?

Comment: A similar expression exists in Spanish (deriving from the Arabic) - "ojalá". It also means "God willing" or "hopefully".

Comment: For further reading: _[Non-religious mentions of God (or religious concepts) in the American English language](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16128/5822)_.

Comment: I have been taught (Spanish foreign language classes in American schools) that *ojala que* can be used in a similar manner as *espero que*. Great for generating variety.

Comment: My favorite variant is the phrase Hank Williams Sr. sometimes used to end his shows:  "Lord willin' and the creek don't rise, we'll see you before long."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"God willing" means "If God allows this to be so," so it has a religious connotations.
 Other phrases that do not have religious connotation include **"If Fate decrees"**, and **"If the wind blows right"**, or **"Hope its my lucky day"**, all of which relates to the future, but does not have the religious connotation **"God willing"** has.

Answer (score 5):

How about the expression *knock on wood*.[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knocking_on_wood)

Comment: Nice alternative! Don't forget the variant "touch wood".

Comment: In my experience, “knock on wood” is more usual in AmE and “touch wood” in BrE, though I don’t know how universal that is.

Answer (score 4):

One of the origins for the phrase "God Willing" or the Latin *deo volente* is in the Bible from the letter of [James 4:14-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=james%204:14-15&version=nrsv)

> <sup>14</sup> Yet you do not even know what tomorrow will bring. What is your life? For you are a mist that appears for a little while and then vanishes. <sup>15</sup> Instead you ought to say, “If the Lord wishes, we will live and do this or that.”

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "God willing" is of the type of phrases that are added so that the speaker does not jinx their good luck by speaking to freely about it.

So, equivalent godless phrases are other kinds of protective magic against the envy of demons (like knocking on wood).

I don't know if there are many people who want to avoid using a religious phrase, but need to protect against demons, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some:

Barring some unforeseen (circumstance/incident/accident).

If things work out.

If things go according to plan.

If the Fates decree. (This phrase used to have religious connotations, but who believes in the Fates any more?)

If (I/we/they) get lucky.

If luck is with (me/us/them).

Comment: "God willing and the creek don't rise": https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=ueS&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=%22god+willing+and+the+creek+don%27t+rise%22&oq=%22god+willing+and+the+creek+don%27t+rise%22&gs_l=serp.3...23239.23239.0.23544.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.32.serp..1.0.0.fg1HBpFd9SI

Answer (score 1):

it's the direct English translation of the Arabic phrase [Inshallah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inshallah_%28disambiguation%29)

> The word Inshallah (Arabic: إنشالله‎),
>   also spelt in various other ways,
>   ("Inshalla"; "Inshala";
>   "Inshaa'Allaah"; Ishallah), is a
>   transliteration of Insha'Allah, (the
>   Arabic: إن شاء الله‎) meaning "God
>   willing".

so in Arabic-speaking countries, it could have a religious connotation

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. Perhaps for not providing some reference that the English is due to the Arabic and not just a similar phrase that happens to exist in both languages. It is an interesting question.

Comment: Also I just found out there is a Latin phrase *deo volente* which could be an alternative source for English *God willing*. It's even possible that the Latin is a calque of the Arabic.

Comment: +1: although *Inshallah* is used in non-Arabic countries with no specific religious intent. For instance, you may hear it (not too rarely) in the South of France where there is a big North-African influence. However it has lost its religious connotation or, at least, it's Islamic religious connotation.

Comment: @pageman, @hippietrail: Never say never, but I would be astonished if it truly could be established that English speakers only say "God willing" because of translation from the same mundane sentiment in Arabic. Next we'll be told that if God *isn't* willing, we only say "That's life" because it's translated from "C'est la vie".

Comment: @hippietrail - as a sidenote, *deo volente* sometimes turns up, mostly in written rather than spoken English, as the abbreviation *d.v.*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- agreed 100%: there is such a thing as overanalysis & I think I see it looming here!

Comment: @AAT: I'm a bit leery of saying any more than "agreed" in case I start overanalysing myself. But now you mention it - yes, I'm familiar with "*d.v.*" in very old texts. But I'd probably stop reading in disgust if I found it in anything recent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've lived in the Middle East & Central Asia and you'd be surprised how this phrase comes up in analytical BUT everyday conversations. For example, if you say - "Let's meet tomorrow, okay?". They would say "God willing". When you ask, "But, you'll be here, tomorrow; right?". They will say "If it be the will of Allah, then we will be here tomorrow.". In their worldview/weltanschauung, it is presumptuous to even assume for you to know where you will be tomorrow.

Comment: @pageman: I wouldn't want to decry such usage by individuals in those areas. As you say, it's part of the culture. But I live in the UK where public life is far more secular. I'm no more fanatically anti-religion than I am homophobic, but by and large I'd rather not have such things paraded in front of me. Do it in the privacy of your own home by all means. Just spare me the details.

Answer (score 1):

> "God willing" or "If is God's will",
>   sometimes spoken as DV; the Latin
>   abbreviation for Deo volente or simply
>   "God willing". In Arabic speaking
>   countries the term is used by members
>   of all religions; meaning the term in
>   and of itself does not denote a
>   religion, but simply means "God
>   willing."

Answer (score 0):

"Lord willing and the creek don't rise" is a sort of backwoods phrase that has the same meaning, but is more folksy and less devoted.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a Muslim and an Arab, the word "inshaa Allah' 'إن شاء الله' means ' If God Wills'  .
It's like saying " I'm gonna visit you tomorrow inshaa Allah". It means I am gonna visit you tomorrow if Allah wills.

This is because we don't know the future, only God knows and everything is under his control and his will.

We say this expression because it is in the Quran, the holy book of Islam when Allah commanded prophet Mohammad (pbuh) to say it in these verses :-

(18:23) "And never say of anything, "Indeed, I will do that tomorrow," "

(18:24) "Except [when adding], "If Allah wills." And remember your Lord when you forget [it] and say, "Perhaps my Lord will guide me to what is nearer than this to right conduct." "