# English idiom equivalent to "Sugar to your mouth"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

In my native language, we have an expression :-

> *sugar to your mouth*.

It is used to express a wish or hope that what the speaker is saying may come true.

Is there a similar expression in either American or British English?

Comment: I'll ignore appeals to [your preferred deity] to answer your prayer ("God willing", etc.). But we have many idiomatic expressions suitable for a range of contexts. One that's primarily *British* is ***More power to your elbow*** - said by way of approval / encouragement to someone who's just set out some proposed action or goal that you completely agree with, and would like to see come to pass. But the ***exact*** context affects which turns of phrase might be appropriate.

Comment: [What follows this is not an answer, just a comment for clarification.] I immediately wanted to say *that's music to my ears*, but while it *sounds* the most similar to *sugar to your mouth*, it doesn't appear as if it has the same meaning. In short, please provide a sentence (or pair of sentences) in which *sugar to your mouth* would actually be used, so that what you're looking for can be put into the exact context—and an on-topic answer can be given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An equivalent to this idiom which is used in English is **from your mouth to God’s ears** (or … **to the gates of Heaven**).

Refer to [What is the origin of the phrase "from your lips to God’s ears?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64936/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-from-your-lips-to-god-s-ears) for more information regarding this idiom as well as its origin.

Comment: We have exactly the same expression in our native language - "May God hear your words". "Sugar to your mouth" is similar in meaning but the difference is that it does not have a religious connotation.

Comment: @Beqa For a way to express this without any religious connotation, you can simple say "may your words come true".

Answer (score 1):

**God willing!**

Quoting https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/god-willing

> used for saying that you hope there will be no problems with your plans

Quoting a ELU answer - https://english.stackexchange.com/a/26350/131620

> *"God willing" means "If God allows this to be so," so it has a religious connotations.
> Other phrases that do not have religious connotation include "If Fate decrees", and "If the wind blows right", or "Hope its my lucky day", all of which relates to the future, but does not have the religious connotation "God willing" has.*

Quoting http://chrisbrauns.com/2009/10/what-d-v-means-and-why-we-should-use-it-often/

> *“D.V.”* refers to the Latin phrase, *“Deo Volente”* and means, *“God
> willing.”*"
>
> James 4:13-17  tells us why
> we should use it often:
>
> *Come now, you who say, “Today or tomorrow we will go into such and
> such a town and spend a year there and trade and make a profit”— yet
> you do not know what tomorrow will bring. What is your life? For you
> are a mist that appears for a little time and then vanishes. Instead
> you ought to say, “If the Lord wills, we will live and do this or
> that.” As it is, you boast in your arrogance. All such boasting is
> evil. So whoever knows the right thing to do and fails to do it, for
> him it is sin. (James 4:13-17)."*

Answer (score -4):

How about **music to one's ears**? From Lexico:

> [**music to one's ears**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/music_to_one%27s_ears): Something that is very pleasant or gratifying to hear or discover.

Example:

> If that turns out to be true, it will be **music to my ears**.

**Music to one's ears** conveys the same sentiment as *sugar to one's mouth*, with "music" corresponding to "sugar" and "ears" to "mouth".

Comment: I don't believe this is the right phrase. It sounds the most similar to the original, but I think it has a different meaning. I actually just finished writing a comment to that effect under the question.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks, but I don't agree.

Comment: I agree with Jason Bassford here. They are not quite related. Consider this exchange between two imaginary friends-- A: You are soon going to get promoted. B: Thanks! From your mouth to God's ears. B (after getting promoted) : Hey I just got the news that I got promoted. Boy, the news was music to my ears.